# ftp_get fails but no error reported by PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I trying to get a file from an FTP server using ftp_get from PHP 5.3.3 (linux build).
I can login, I can list the files, but the ftp_get command does not download the file.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
$ftp_user_name = DBUSER;
$ftp_user_pass = DBUSERPASS;
$ftp_server = HOST;
$local_file = "poutarde.odt";
$server_file = "poutarde.odt";

// set up a connection to ftp server
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// turn passive mode on
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
  echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
  echo "There was a problem\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

The "poutarde.odt" file is at the root of the FTP.

I checked the FTP download from a client (filezilla) and everything works perfectly.
However, using ftp_get, I get nothing (except the echo "There was a problem"), no even a PHP error, it just fails.

Thank you for you help.

Reno

Comment: Sniff the FTP session using Wireshark, and check that your PHP script can write to $local_file.

Comment: You might want to make sure that ftp_connect and ftp_login aren't returning false, your code is currently assuming that the connection and login worked.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the problem seems to have been caused by insufficient file permissions, not by anything in the code itself.

Comment: Try toggling pasive mode. It worked for me.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

[ftp_get](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fget.php) expects a file handler, not a filename.

```
$local_file = fopen("poutarde.odt",'w');
//...
if(ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY))
```

Comment: $local_file actually needed a temp path as in "/tmp/poutarde.odt" with write privileges for www-data.

Thanks for the help!

Reno

Comment: @ben you wrote `ftp_get` but linked `ftp_fget` (which does require the file handler). Normal `ftp_get` takes a string.